# Redirect all urls to https with .htaccess, except images (in Symfony2)

Tags: .htaccess, symfony

i have tried but no result, it's my `.htaccess`.

```
  ...
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^exampe\.com$ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.bmp)$
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.exampe.com/$1 [R=301,L]

        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.bmp)$
        RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
        RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

        RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
        RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]
...
```

when i try to go `http://example.com/image.jpg` it redirects me on `https://example.com`

Comment: Why bother hacking away at the `.htaccess` when you can [do this instead](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/scheme.html)?

Comment: i am also using FOSRest, is it possible to use "HTTPS Force Routes" with it ?

Comment: Sure, just use the `schemes` attribute in the REST route generator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have these rules based on `THE_REQUEST`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\.(png|jpg|gif|jpeg|bmp)
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.(png|jpg|gif|jpeg|bmp)
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Make sure to test in a new browser to avoid old browser caches.

Comment: Whenever I start working with http requests, I am sure I will love these answers of you :)

Answer (score 2):

It might be better to let Symfony do this for you, in `app/config/security.yml`

```
security:
    # ...
    access_control:
        # Force images to use HTTP
        - { path: \.(png|jpg|gif|jpeg|bmp)$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: http }
        # Force everything else on HTTPS
        - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
```

You can read more about it in the docs:

- [current](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_control.html#forcing-a-channel-http-https)
- [3.2](http://symfony.com/doc/3.2/security/access_control.html#forcing-a-channel-http-https)
- [2.8](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/security/access_control.html#forcing-a-channel-http-https)